# Internet works with router, but not when using another router in between

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, router, internet

I have:

Internet Router:  **SpeedTouch 585**

2nd Router:              **DLink DI-604**

When connecting my computers directly to the SpeedTouch internet works. But when connecting the DLink to the SpeedTouch, and computers to the DLink, I get no connection. What I need to do to make this work?

I'm running XP on one laptop and Win7 on another, same issue on both.

Comment: Can you reach the other computers while connected through the hub?

Comment: Yes, I have a home network I use for sharing files. With XP / XP this worked both ways. Now I installed Win7 on one, so have Win7 / XP, and I can see the XP pc from Win7, not other way, but I think that's a different issue.

Comment: Hm, it should work without configuration actually. Can you `ping` the router? Are you using DHCP or static IP addresses?

Comment: Yes I can ping the router, and log on to the SpeedTouch setup. Not sure if I'm using DHCP or static, where can I find out?

Comment: That's really weird because your connection settings should be okay if you can ping the router. See if its IP address is entered as the Gateway when you [change the TCP/IP settings](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings).

Comment: That part number you give for the "Hub" actually shows up as a router on the D-Link support site. That will make a big difference as to how it is configured and used. Please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: @Tog: Oh, sorry. It may be a router, honestly I don't really know the difference.

Comment: @slhck: If I go to IPv4 properties it's all set to automatic. Clicking advanced, shows DHCP Enabled, and under Default Gateways, nothing is entered.

Comment: A hub is a dumb network device that lets everything go everywhere, a router/switch requires setting up and some can't be used as a network extender. I hope your lucky with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the fact that

- You can reach all other computers
- You can reach the other router and its setup page
- Your connection settings seem fine

My suggestions:

1. Make sure that you connect the routers using one of the DLink's 4 LAN ports and **not** the single WAN port that should be used for connecting to the modem.
2. Also, you should enter the IP address of your first router as the gateway, otherwise the computers won't know where to "look for their internet connection".
3. You should disable DHCP on one of the devices. Most probably it's running it on both, which can cause serious confusion. I'd disable all kinds of network services on the DLink, as it then merely acts as a switch.

[image]

Comment: Which router you mean?  I connect SpeedTouch LAN1 port, to DLink WAN port. Then computers to DLINK LAN1 and LAN2.  Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, don't connect it to the DLink's WAN port, but to one of its LAN ports.

Comment: It works! :)  Using the LAN port, specified gateway address on both computers, and reseted the DLink. The DHCP I can't seem to be able to change. All buttons are disabled. Or maybe that is set up in the router?

Comment: If the buttons are disabled it might be disabled anyway, so that's fine :) If it's running, leave it at that. If my solution worked for you, consider accepting the answer so the question is closed. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yea, idk, it looks like this http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/5420/ss20110513125841.png   Ok, thanks for the help! :)